# Why is the meaning of dead zone different in The Dead Zone book, movie, and TV show?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, deadzone

In the book, the dead zone refers to words, memories, or abilities he lost because of brain damage from the car accident.

In the movie, the dead zone seems to be a blank spot in some of his visions that means he can change the outcome of that vision.

In the TV show, the dead zone is the part of his brain that gives him his ability.

Why did they change the meaning of the dead zone as they went from the book to the movie to the TV show?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: most books (and especially Stephen King books) are difficult to adapt word-for-word. Ideas have to be cut, reworked, and reorganized to cut into a hour and a half movie or a season's worth of television. Adding onto that the fact that the three pieces were written by three different people with different ideas of what would work with audiences.

As a fun thought experiment, can you name a successful Stephen King movie or TV series where the main mystical conceit of the book wasn't altered or abridged in some meaningful way?